# cannot run log method in config method for angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I'm trying to intercept specific calls and show an alert to the user.  There's already existing code on our project that looks like:

```
 myModule.config([
        '$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', "$httpProvider", 
        ($routeProvider: ng.route.IRouteProvider, $locationProvider: ng.ILocationProvider, $httpProvider: ng.IHttpProvider) => {
            console.log("in my module");

            if (history.pushState) {
                $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

                $routeProvider.when('/projects', {
                    template: Templates.projects,
                    controller: projectsListControllerName
                });
            } else {
                $routeProvider.when('/', {
                    template: Templates.projects,
                    controller: projectsListControllerName
                });
            }
        }
    ]);
```

Is there something wrong with `console.log("in my module");` in the config method of myModule?  My routes still work going to /projects and /, but I never see "in my module" in the console.

Comment: `console.log()` in config should be fine. Looks like something else is broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there something wrong with console.log("in my module"); in the config method of myModule?

Nope. It's okay

> My routes still work going to /projects and /, but I never see "in my module" in the console.

`/` is guaranteed to work as long as you have a server route returning `/`. Most likely the same is applying for `/projects` i.e. the server is returning the page but client side angular isn't picking up the details for `/projects`

## What is broken?

Most likely you don't have an `ng-app` pointing to the module or if you are using `requirejs` you are missing a `angular.bootstrap` call *after* you load this file.